# Combine URL rewriting (to force https) with http auth?

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting, http-authentication

I have a domain, `mattpotts.com` and have set up a sub-domain `dev.mattpotts.com` for me to develop on and will then copy the files to the normal domain when they're ready to go.

My directory structure is as follows and `dev.mattpotts.com` points to `dev/`

```
+-public_html/
  +-project1/
  +-project2/
  +-project3/
  +-dev/
    +-project1
    +-project2
    +-project3
```

I basically want to be able to go from `http://mattpotts.com/project1` to `https://dev.mattpotts.com/project1` by adding `dev.`.

I have the following `.htaccess` in `dev/` and it works, all  this needs to do is force https.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dev 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dev.mattpotts.com$1 [R,L]
```

I want to force https so that I can securely use http auth on the directory. However, when I combine it with the following rules, it doesn't work. I have my `.htpasswd` set up but I've not even had the login form show up yet.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Dev Protected Area"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

**How can I successfully combine the to set of** `.htaccess` **rules?**

Edit, very strange things are happening!

https://dev.mattpotts.com/project1/ displays 'hello!' from non dev version of site (note https)
http://dev.mattpotts.com/project1/ displays 'hello dev!' (as desired) from dev version. What's going on here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've told us where your `.htaccess` file is, but you haven't told us where your `.htpasswd` file is. According to the Apache documentation on [AuthUserFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html#authuserfile):

> **Syntax:**   AuthUserFile *file-path*
>
> *File-path* is the path to the user
>   file. If it is not absolute (*i.e.*, if
>   it doesn't begin with a slash), it is
>   treated as relative to the `ServerRoot`.

So in other words, it is looking for the `.htpasswd` in somewhere like `/etc/apache2/.htpasswd`. So either move your `.htpasswd` file there, or make your directive contain an absolute path to the file, e.g.:

```
AuthType     Basic
AuthName     "Dev Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/mattpots.com/public_html/dev/.htpasswd
Require      valid-user
```

However, for security reasons, I highly recommend keeping your `.htpasswd` file outside of your document root.

Answer (score 0):

These issues should be independent of each other: do I understand correctly that the "force HTTPS" part works?

That said, `AuthUserFile .htpasswd` may be looking for .htpasswd in the wrong place. The easiest fix is to put the full path and name there, e.g. `AuthUserFile /home/matt/www/public_html/dev/.htpasswd` (or wherever you have the dev directory).

Comment: I've set the .htpasswd path correctly now and it's working but I'm not sure how well! Can you please try http://dev.mattpotts.com/project1/ and http://mattpotts.com/dev/project1/ they should both be protected by auth but I don't think the former is.